# Do $\operatorname{Hom}( - , R)$ and $ - \otimes_R B$ commute when applied to $A\cong R^d?$

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $A$ and $B$ are $R$-modules, and further suppose that $A$ is free with finite rank. Is it true that

$$ \operatorname{Hom} (A \otimes_R B , R) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(A,R)\otimes_R B$$

where the homomorphisms are those of $R$-modules? In other words, do the operations of dualizing $\operatorname{Hom}( - , R)$ and tensoring $ - \otimes_R B$ commute when applied to $A?$

If not, what about in the special case $R = \mathbb{Z}$ (so that $A\cong \mathbb{Z}^d$) and $B=\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Is this true when $A=R$ is free of rank $1$?

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathrm{Hom}(-,R)$, $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,R)$ or $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(-,R)$?

Comment: @user68316, (the negative answer does not depend on which one is meant :-) )

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Using $R\otimes_R B \cong B$ gives me $\operatorname{Hom}_R (B, R)$ on the left, and I can also see the right side is $\cong B.$ These would be isomorphic if $B$ was also free of finite rank I think.

Comment: Well, your question does impose conditions on $B$, so the only sensible interpretation is, does this isomorphoism hold for all $B$? If you intended to ask something else, it would be a good idea to be more explicit about it!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez By my last sentence I did not mean to imply that I know anything if $B$ is not free of finite rank. I still want to know the answer for all $B,$ I was just saying that I at least know the answer for this special case and I'm not sure if it holds otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I can see this is false at least in the case where $R$ is a field (since a vector space is isomorphic to its dual if and only if it is finite dimensional). So the general part of the question has been answered, but I am still not sure for my special case.

Comment: Your special case with $R=\mathbb Z$, $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\mathbb R$ asks whether $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. You can easily compute $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z)$ by noticing that $\mathbb R$ is a [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It took me a while to see the relevance that the real are a divisible group but I've got it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a positive spin: there is an isomorphism $\hom_R(A\otimes B,R)\cong\hom_R(A,R)\otimes_RB$ whenever $B$ is projective and finitely generated.

Answer (score 0):

**In general no**, look at $R=\mathbb Z$, $A=\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Z/2$.

<s>If $B=\mathbb R$, there **happens to be** an isomorphism as you would like, but it is not natural.</s>

Even if $R=\mathbb Z$, $A=\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb R$, the statement is false, see Mariano's comment below. To see that $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb Z(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z)$ cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, <s>notice, for instance, that the first group is not divisible</s> because it vanishes.

There **is** of course an isomorphism if $B=R$.

Comment: Are you saying that $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ as an abelian group?

Comment: Oops! Apparently I'm saying that, even though it's complete rubbish. ;) ${}{}$ (will edit)

Comment: $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z)$ **is** divisible, because it is zero :-)

Comment: Ouch. I should stop doing this. ;) ${}{}$ (will edit)